# Yii2 Active Record class load() or save() not updating data

Tags: activerecord, yii2

The following is the controller code that seems to be working through the if statement but the data in the db is not updating.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($_model = Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem lies in something to do with the fact that it is part of a CRUD code for of users and the form only updates a handful of fields (excluding password, authKey, etc).

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code from

```
if ($_model = Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->save()) {
```

to :

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
```

Comment: wow, thanks!! I was f**king around with that for a while.. my eyes just couldn't see it I guess.